# gcloud compute engine windows server port 8080

Tags: tomcat, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I setup a gcloud vminstance for windows 2012 and have apache tomcat installed

I can access from within the server by doing localhost:8080 and see the apache tomcat home page.

I have a static ip setup and have setup firewall rules tcp:8080 and udp:8080 for both http and https (though I need only http) as mentioned here
[Can't open port 8080 on Google Compute Engine running Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880703/cant-open-port-8080-on-google-compute-engine-running-debian/25885723#25885723)

but no luck yet I cannot get to this from outside of gcloud...when I try my static up from outside I do not get anything....I can ping ip address but not ip address:8080 (not sure if its possible to ping with port number)

from the browser (outside gcloud) I get
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

update - For testing I disabled the Windows firewall and no luck yet. I have now re enabled the firewall and will try to create a new instance...and just try port 80 ...will not install apache tomcat while testing this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of possibilities here:

1. **Packets are being stopped by the GCP firewall.**

   One way to test this would be to create a Linux VM with identical firewall settings, and see if you can receive packets there. This is a decent amount of work, though.
2. **Packets are being stopped by a Windows firewall.**

   See [Managing the Windows Sever 2012 Firewall](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/managing-the-windows-server-2012-firewall) for information on checking these firewall settings.
3. **Apache Tomcat is listening on the wrong network interface.**

   What happens if you log into the Windows 2012 and instead of opening `localhost:8080` in your browser, you open `[Windows IP address]:8080` (try various IP addresses associated with your VM instance; you should have an "internal" one and an "external" one. Check the output of `ipconfig`, as well as the Cloud Console).

   If none of these (besides the localhost IP) works, Tomcat is misconfigured.

Comment: For #3...I am able to see localhost:8080....and internal_ip:8080 ...but external_ip:8080 even remotely within has no  luck)...same error as above              I will now try #2 and see what happens...BTW when I do an ipconfig from within the server I am not able to see the external_ip and am assuming that is normal....(PS...I am far from an admin...so pardon anything funny that I say)

Comment: Hmm...the other really easy things to try: (1) create another VM inside GCP, and check `<internal IP>:8080`, and (2) mess around with the Windows firewall settings, then try again externally.

Comment: I just switched off the firewall totally and no luck yet....(obviously I believe I have to turn it back on after testing....) and just to be clear....internal_ip:8080 works fine and I can see apache tomcat home page..I am also able to ping external ip address from outsise cloud......am I supposed to see external ip when I do a ip config, that I do not see...thx –

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the machine you're trying to access since updating the network configuration? I was just able to do this on a Windows VM.