# node js "hello world" google cloud VM

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to make the simplest "hello world" example of express server in node js , on a google VM machine and it does not work.
What I am trying to do is NOT use the APP ENGINE of google , I am just trying as a 1st step to create a NODE JS server on the google compute machine and connect by http.
I used the google code example of "hello world" for node js and to use the http://MY_VM_EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS:8080 to connect in the browser - no luck.
I am sure I am missing something stupid but not sure what :-(.

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Hello, world!');
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the port is not open from the cloud side. I have never had to open the port from the OS side for node server, unless you have specially setup a firewall to do so.

In Azure, I had to go in the "Endpoints" section and add the port to open.

In AWS, I had to create an Inbound Rule in the Security Group

Google must have a similar setting. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880703/cant-open-port-8080-on-google-compute-engine-running-debian) answer