# Access Oracle Apex from remote machine

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-apex, firewall

Hi all I have successfully installed Oracle 11g Express addition on a Linux VM (google cloud compute)
I have sqlplus working and I can query data.
The listener is also working.

But as there is no GUI with Linux servers I cannot try local host and external machines have the connection refused.

My Questions are:

1) Does Apex come pre-installed on Oracle XE it used to but not mentioned anywhere.

2)  if the ip address of the server is 123.123.123 what url would I use to get to apex from a remote machine? I have tried

- http://123.123.123:8080/apex/
- http://123.123.123/apex/
- https://123.123.123:8080/apex/

3) How can I tell if it is the server or Oracle refusing the connection?

Firewall

```
 $ netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:50776        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:43548        10.128.0.3:1521         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:50722        169.254.169.254:80      CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:50814        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.3:50774        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     64 10.128.0.3:22           74.125.41.105:38312     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::40070                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::1521                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 10.128.0.3:1521         10.128.0.3:43548        ESTABLISHED
```

Listener

```
 $ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-AUG-2017 02:59:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                22-AUG-2017 02:00:17
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 59 min. 33 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/centossmallblockpro/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=centossmallblockpro.c.sincere-destiny-176110.internal)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=centossmallblockpro.c.sincere-destiny-176110.internal)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

SQLPLUS working

```
    sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Aug 22 03:03:51 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system
Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X
```

.

```
Telnet XX.XXX.XXX.XX 8080

Telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great answers to 1 and 2  from Bjarte but the actual problem was not the Linux firewall but the Compute engine firewall.

I didn't know it even existed, when you select the check box to open Http it created a rule to TCP:80 but I needed TCP:8080.

Here is the article that solved it for me [cant open port on google compute engine ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880703/cant-open-port-8080-on-google-compute-engine-running-debian)

Answer (score 2):

1) Oracle XE (11g) comes with APEX version 3.2 I think. This is a very old APEX release. Follow the instructions how to drop this old version and get the latest from [otn.oracle.com](http://otn.oracle.com). Latest version should also work with 11g XE.

2) Tunnel

You can create a ssh-tunnel from your desktop machine to the end-point server where your services are running. Now you can access services on remote machine from your desktop environment aka. sqlplus, SQL Developer, Firefox, etc..

```
# Access Your Database Remotely Through an SSH Tunnel
# ssh -L [local port]:[database host]:[remote port] [username]@[remote host]
# console 1: 9998 is just an arbitrary port > 1024. Can be anything.
ssh -N -L 9998:10.128.0.3:1521 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@35.184.136.98
# console 2:
sqlplus user/pwd@localhost:9998/XE 
# firefox:
http://localhost:9998/apex
```

Comment: 1) thanks for that at least I know I should be able to see apex remotely. 2) Sound like a good way to test out the local host, where can I find out more about this? 3) any idea why remote machines cant access via normal browsing?

Comment: You need to configure the security scheme for your cloud instance and grant HTTP access to the whole world - or just your ip. So far you probably just have admin access over port 22 (SSH).