# Remote connection to Oracle DB via internet using a web browser

Tags: oracle, networking, oracle11g

I installed Oracle Db 11g Express Edition and upgraded to Apex 5.1(computer A), the installation went well.  I had the ISP assign a static ip address to the computer, they forwarded the ports (8080) to the router and I am able to ping the computer's static ip from a computer on a different network via the internet (computer B).  However when I enter http://ipaddress:8080/apex/f?p=4550, I get ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

lsnrctl status

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                03-JAN-2018 20:37:52
Uptime                    0 days 15 hr. 59 min. 21 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Legacy-PC\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Legacy-PC)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I can connect to the database from computer "B" via sqlplus by using:
SQL> connect username/password@host_ip:1521.

I can also connect to the computer via remote desktop by using the static ip address that was assigned to that computer.

The idea is to allow other people to access the db from a web browser by using http://host_ip:8080/apex/f?p=104...

I did find a few post here on stackoverflow and followed some of the procedures that I thought were applicable but they did not work, some of them were:

[How to connect to Oracle 11g database remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108320/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11g-database-remotely)

[Access Oracle Apex from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808308/access-oracle-apex-from-remote-machine)

Where can I find more information regarding this issue?  Has anyone else had similar problems that may help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: were you able to access http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4550 from same machine where you have installed ?

Comment: Yes, no issues connecting locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the response.  I finally found a fix in the documentation, I feel kind of silly for not finding it before I posted my question.

The command

```
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
```

fixed my issue.  I had seen this also on an earlier post but at the time, I was not sure it applied to my situation.  I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9534356100346776767) says that

> That's a standard error when you try to connect to a host:port and
>   nothing is listening on that port.
>
> You'll need to ensure that you have something listening on that port,
>   either
>
> - ORDS
> - embedded plsql gateway