# Google Cloud Server Can't Connect to Anaconda port

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, port

UPDATE: When I try to connect with all my original settings using a different wifi network, everything works again. There is something wrong with this particular wifi network. Is it possible that this network blocks all http connections?

I set up a Google cloud instance following these instructions here: https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52 .

Everything works great for about 2 weeks. Suddenly I have my server running in a tmux window, move to a new physical location (switching wifi networks by doing so) and am unable to reconnect to the server getting the "ERR Connection timed out" message. I have tried restarting the server, updating it, changing the port Anaconda uses, changing my tcp port, changing the way that I launch the Anaconda port, looking at my Firewalls, adding a ucp port instruction (as suggested here: [Can't open port 8080 on Google Compute Engine running Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880703/cant-open-port-8080-on-google-compute-engine-running-debian) ). Yet none of these things have managed to allow me to reconnect to the Anaconda port and continue working on my project. I am very motivated to find out what in the world went wrong so suddenly and how I can fix it without wiping my server and starting a new one from scratch.

I am using the latest version of Chrome and my wifi works for doing everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that I solved that problem. Fast.ai forum discussion (@kro answer) and post from Google Platform Blog helped me a lot:

- https://forums.fast.ai/t/can-t-connect-to-jupyter-notebook-tried-3-different-machines-err-connection-timed-out/3779/22
- https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/07/Connection-Refused.html

As I understood, the problem was in the port, which we want to use (for example, 5100). The thing is that the port listens to only localhost IP. We should add 0.0.0.0 as default route for non-local traffic by this command (it worked for me only in Cloud Shell):

```
$ gcloud compute routes create default-internet --destination-range 0.0.0.0/0 --next-hop-gateway default-internet-gateway
```

And after that to start jupiter notebook by this command:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=5100 --no-browser &
```

Also, we can check the network routes:

```
$ gcloud compute routes list
```

After adding default route such a line appeared: 
NAME, NETWORK, DEST_RANGE, NEXT_HOP, PRIORITY
default-internet, default, 0.0.0.0/0, default-internet-gateway, 1000
[image]